# Comparing the content of two character columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to compare if the content of one column is equal or different from the content of another.

```
Response <- c("Old", "New", "Old", "New")
Correct_answer <- c("New", "Old", "Old", "New")
comparison <- data.frame(Response, Correct_answer)
```

I tried this:

```
mutate(comparison, Resp_final = ifelse(grepl("Old", Response), "1",
                                  ifelse(grepl("New", Response), "2", "")))
```

But it only checks for the "Response" column. How can I compare both "Response" and "Correct_answer" columns and get the result in one column using dplyr?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to check for equality, or do you also want to check for *how* they are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the columns you want to compare are factors that have a different number of levels, you'll probably want to convert them to character first, otherwise, it will throw an error.

Showing how the error occurs:

```
fruits1 <- as.factor(c("grape", "lemon", "watermelon",
 "apple", "banana","avocado", "lemon","watermelon"))

fruits2 <- as.factor(c("lemon", "grape", "orange",
"apple", "grape","avocado","lemon","grape"))

df <- data.frame(fruits1, fruits2)

#Comparing:

df %>% 
  mutate(comparison = if_else(
    fruits1 == fruits2, "equal", "different"))

#Throws an error
```

Fixing it inside the pipe:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(comparison = if_else(
   as.character(fruits1) == as.character(fruits2), "equal", "different"))
```

Answer (score 11):

If the only thing you care about is equality, then a simple `if_else` will do:

```
comparison %>% mutate(Resp_final = if_else(Response == Correct_answer, 1, 0))
```

But if you want to compare not only whether they are equal but also *how* they are equal, you can do that with `case_when` like so:

```
comparison %>% 
  mutate(Resp_final = case_when(
   Response == Correct_answer & Response == "Old" ~ "1",
   Response == Correct_answer & Response == "New" ~ "2",
   TRUE                                           ~ ""))
```

Output:

```
## Response Correct_answer resp_final
## 1        Old            New           
## 2        New            Old           
## 3        Old            Old          1
## 4        New            New          2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I want to know not only how the two columns are equal, but also how they differ. For example, if there is a "New" in the Response column, and a "Old" in the Correct_answer column, I would like to see that difference reflected in the  resp_final.

Comment: Just add them as conditionals to the case_when function

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that.

Comment: @yeedle Does `case_when` work well in `mutate`? I read in RStudio Blog, it says "case_when() is still somewhat experiment and does not currently work inside mutate(). That will be fixed in a future version."

Comment: @yeedle This is with regards to the latest version, 0.5.0. https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/

Comment: It depends how you define "well"... For the case presented in @Simon's question it should work fine. In more complicated cases, column names need to be prefixed by `.$` for it to work. This is an [issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1719) that is actively been worked on and will probably be working completely soon enough.

Comment: The solution given by @yeedle using the data in this question works  just fine. However, when I adapt this code to a bigger data set, the names of the columns need to be prefixed by .$. In addition, I am having trouble comparing the content of two columns when there are more than two conditions. In my case, I not only want to see if the values in two columns are the same (e.g., "New" and "New", "Old" and "Old"), but also if they are different (e.g., "New" and "Old", "Old" and "New").

Comment: @Simon, all you have to add are the conditions:   `Response == "New"  ~ "3", Response == "Old" ~ "4",` after the first two conditions, and that would take into account changes as well.

Comment: `case_when` evaluates the conditions top to bottom, so as soon as it finds a matching condition, it'll apply the right hand expression. Since the first two conditions cover both cases where the 2 cols are equal, the rest of the cols will only apply if the 2 are not equal.

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding the two other conditions as @yeedle suggested, but it did not work. As explained, 'case_when' does not evaluate conditions 3 and 4; it only evaluates conditions 1 and 2. Is there any other ways to do this comparison without using dplyr? Thanks!